# How secure is the ClientStorageAPI?

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I'm using ClientStorageAPI to store some user's data and I had a doubt: How secure is it?

I mean, is it possible for an experienced user to change the client keys?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in Android, `ClientStorageAPI` data is saved in the application's [private storage area](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). This data is secured in the sense that neither other applications nor the user himself can read or alter it, because each app is sandboxed.

However, this restriction [does not apply if the device has been rooted](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/45983).

As always when security is concerned, re-checking in sever-side code is highly recommended.